# usage of concat function

Tags: sql

Write a query to display address details by concatenating address and city of students . Give an alias as Address and sort the result based on the concatenated column in descending order.

Comment: 1. Please share the RDBMS this is being performed on as the concatenation operator/function is different for each one. 2. [With homework you should show an attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) so we can help guide from there instead of just doing the work for you. We are all here because we like to help folks out and it doesn't feel like helping to just do homework for folks so we are less inclined to offer an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can Concatenate using pipe symbol || in oracle or use + symbol in sql server.Once you concatenate give alias name (address1 || address 2)as address, sorting is done by order by clause .

provide some sample to help you